# How to debug no audio on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: bug-reporting

I suddenly have no audio and no video playback in any program after installing updates.
It works on another OS on the same hardware. I have also tried several sound cards; no success.

System:

```
Linux land 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I debug that? I don't even know where to start.

I see this in dmesg:

```
  726.053889] INFO: task pulseaudio:4079 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
[  726.053900]       Not tainted 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  726.053903] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  726.053905] task:pulseaudio      state:D stack:0     pid:4079  ppid:3996   flags:0x00000002
[  726.053913] Call Trace:
[  726.053916]  <TASK>
[  726.053921]  __schedule+0x2b7/0x5f0
[  726.053933]  ? snd_pcm_hw_rule_add+0x156/0x1b0 [snd_pcm]
[  726.053963]  schedule+0x68/0x110
[  726.053969]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[  726.053975]  __mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x3d8/0x770
[  726.053979]  ? snd_pcm_hw_rule_add+0x156/0x1b0 [snd_pcm]
[  726.054000]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[  726.054004]  mutex_lock+0x3e/0x50
[  726.054008]  dpcm_fe_dai_open+0x43/0x340 [snd_soc_core]
[  726.054055]  ? snd_pcm_hw_constraints_init.isra.0+0x4c0/0x580 [snd_pcm]
[  726.054076]  snd_pcm_open_substream+0x8d/0x170 [snd_pcm]
[  726.054097]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xe/0x20
[  726.054103]  snd_pcm_open.part.0+0xe1/0x210 [snd_pcm]
[  726.054123]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[  726.054129]  snd_pcm_playback_open+0x56/0x90 [snd_pcm]
[  726.054150]  snd_open+0xb9/0x1f0 [snd]
[  726.054168]  chrdev_open+0xc4/0x250
[  726.054172]  ? fsnotify_perm.part.0+0x76/0x1a0
[  726.054178]  ? __pfx_chrdev_open+0x10/0x10
[  726.054182]  do_dentry_open+0x167/0x450
[  726.054187]  vfs_open+0x2d/0x40
[  726.054191]  do_open+0x235/0x4f0
[  726.054197]  ? open_last_lookups+0x9b/0x3c0
[  726.054204]  path_openat+0x11d/0x2a0
[  726.054209]  do_filp_open+0xb2/0x160
[  726.054216]  ? __check_object_size+0x23/0x30
[  726.054223]  ? alloc_fd+0xad/0x1a0
[  726.054229]  do_sys_openat2+0xb3/0x180
[  726.054234]  __x64_sys_openat+0x55/0xa0
[  726.054239]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[  726.054244]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[  726.054250]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[  726.054254]  ? __fget_light+0xb5/0x160
[  726.054259]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[  726.054266]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[  726.054270]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[  726.054274]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[  726.054280]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[  726.054284]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[  726.054288]  ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4e/0xb0
[  726.054292]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x72/0xdc
[  726.054299] RIP: 0033:0x7f907bb14764
[  726.054304] RSP: 002b:00007ffc73b63a40 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
[  726.054309] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000080802 RCX: 00007f907bb14764
[  726.054311] RDX: 0000000000080802 RSI: 00007ffc73b63ae0 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
[  726.054314] RBP: 00007ffc73b63ae0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007ffc73b63857
[  726.054316] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000080802
[  726.054318] R13: 00007f9074231eb2 R14: 00007ffc73b63ae0 R15: 0000000081204101
[  726.054322]  </TASK>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing to try first is to rollback updates. Like install exact previous package version and put it on hold to avoid unwanted update later.

Another thing to try would be to determine what is broken. ALSA drivers, pulseaudio or something else. Try `aplay -l` to list devices and use them with `aplay` to test devices from raw hardware to higher levels. Also try `paplay`.

Check `alsa-info` report contents for possible hints.

That'a all I can suggest for starters. Don't forget to report the bug when you find what package causes it.